# Change to magento indexer process

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I need to make product urls like this "attribute1/attribute2/product-url-key" dynamically. I've found that the urls of every product are in the enterprise_url_rewrite table, request path field.

I would like to make change to the indexer process as well, so the changes will stay when its rerun, but I don't know where it is?

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon! Let's break this down:

> I need to make product urls like this "attribute1/attribute2/product-url-key" dynamically

Yes - you can create URL rewrites dynamically using the Magento models that represent the database table you've identified already:

```
/** @var Enterprise_UrlRewrite_Model_Redirect $rewrite */
$rewrite = Mage::getSingleton('enterprise_urlrewrite/redirect');

// Create new record or load the existing one
$rewrite->loadByRequestPath($requestUrl, $store->getId());

$rewrite
    ->setStoreId($store->getId()) // define which store the rewrite should be
    ->setOptions(null) // specify any rewrite/redirect/custom options
    ->setRequestPath($requestUrl) // specify the request URL
    ->setIdentifier($requestUrl)
    ->setTargetPath($targetPath)  // specify the redirect target
    ->setEntityType(Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::TYPE_CUSTOM)
    ->setDescription('Add a comment if you want to');

$rewrite->save();
```

This will attempt to load an existing URL rewrite/redirect by the `$requestUrl` and will return an empty model if it was not found which you can embellish with your data and save.

The "options" define whether it's a temporary or permanent redirect (302 vs 301).

[More information here](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/search_seo/seo-url-redirect-create.html) via the Magento EE user guide.

> I would like to make change to the indexer process as well, so the changes will stay when its rerun, but I don't know where it is?

Don't worry about it. The (modern) Magento database has table triggers wherever records need to be indexed, and will detect creations, updated and deletions on those tables. The indexers will detect that change need to be made and will make them for you as required.

If you're seeing URL rewrites disappearing it's most likely because you've been adding them directly to the index table with SQL, so the table is rewritten whenever the indexer runs. To avoid this use the model as noted above and everything will be saved into the correct location and indexed properly.

Comment: Thanks for you response Robbie, I am new to magento, where should I write this code?